# Copper texture with oil stains cycles material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm designing a barrel for a weapon (Fallout themed), however I'm having trouble getting this texture:

[image: reference object]

This is the texture I currently have: 
[image: material on object]

There are the nodes for it: 
[image: cycles material nodes]

Does anyone know how I could get a little closer to the top image?

Comment: You can use photo editing software to combine screenshots/renders into a single image if necessary.

Comment: I've made it quickly, check here: http://imgur.com/jxTakeU It's procedural texture, you can control small dirt, big dirt etc.